# How to remove default black color border in react-responsive-carousel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ionic-framework, carousel

I am working in Ionic react . I have added [react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel) for swiping the content, but default there is black color border as show in the image .I have changed the CSS value from CSS file in node modules, but changes do not reflected in content .How can I solve the issue

[image]

```
    <Carousel>
      {
        assignedOrderData&&assignedOrderData.map((item1: any) => item1.map((item: any) =>


          <IonGrid id='dashboard-orders'>
            <IonList onClick={() => history.push(`/myorderdetails/${item.order_id}`)} >
              <IonRow >
                <IonCol style={{ height: '.5px', borderTop: '.5px' }} size='1' class="ion-text-end">
                  <IonIcon icon={timeOutline} color='primary' />
                </IonCol>
                <IonCol size='5'>
                  <IonText class="ion-text-nowrap" color='primary'> Delivery Time: 5 PM </IonText>
                </IonCol>

                <IonCol size='6' class="ion-text-end" >
                  <IonBadge onClick={() => { }}>View Delivery </IonBadge>
                </IonCol>
              </IonRow>

              <IonRow>
                <IonCol size='8' class="ion-text-start">
                  <IonText color='dark' style={{ fontSize: '.8em' }}>   {[item.shipping_address_1, item.shipping_city, item.shipping_postcode].filter(Boolean).join(',  ')} </IonText>
                </IonCol>
                <IonCol class="ion-text-end">
                  <IonText style={{ fontSize: '.8em' }} color='dark' class="ion-text-start"  >Order : # {item?.order_id} </IonText>
                </IonCol>
              </IonRow>

              <IonItem lines='full' color='medium' style={{ height: '.5px', borderTop: '.5px' }}></IonItem>

              <IonRow style={{ paddingTop: '5px' }}>
                <IonCol> <IonText color='dark' class="ion-text-nowrap">5.33 m </IonText></IonCol>
                <IonCol> <IonText color='dark' class="ion-text-nowrap">{item.delivery_time} </IonText></IonCol>
                <IonCol > <IonText color='dark' class="ion-text-nowrap">{item.total_text} </IonText></IonCol>
                <IonCol> <IonText color='dark' class="ion-text-nowrap">{item.payment_method} </IonText></IonCol>
              </IonRow>

              <IonRow style={{ paddingTop: '3px' }}>
                <IonCol> <IonText style={{ fontSize: '.8em' }} class="ion-text-nowrap">Dist </IonText></IonCol>
                <IonCol> <IonText style={{ fontSize: '.8em' }} class="ion-text-nowrap">ETA </IonText></IonCol>
                <IonCol> <IonText style={{ fontSize: '.8em' }} class="ion-text-nowrap">Amount</IonText></IonCol>
                <IonCol> <IonText style={{ fontSize: '.8em' }} class="ion-text-nowrap">Payment</IonText></IonCol>
              </IonRow>
            </IonList>
          </IonGrid>

        ))}
    </Carousel>}
```

Comment: Are you using ionic + react or simple react ?

Comment: @TaylorRahul Ionic +react

Comment: ionic has built in feature for such kind of slides .. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides you can use this instead of other NPM modules

Comment: I have already used it , but I have some issue on it

Comment: Some issue or any issue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65803577/what-is-the-reason-for-following-error-notfounderror-failed-to-execute-remov

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227590/discussion-between-taylor-rahul-and-anee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add some css for this in your page css file.

```
.carousel .slide{
    background: #ff442e!important;
}
```